# Determining which Graphics Card is causing BSOD?

Tags: bsod, hardware-failure

I used to mine Dogecoin with my tower. It has 2x NVidia GTX GeForce 570 2.5 GB graphics cards SLI'd together. I no longer mine but I mined for months, maybe a year, 24/7 and it has shortened the life of my cards.

Now it's crashing whenever the graphics cards get over worked (i.e. playing intense 3D games like SkyRim or Fallout New Vegas). The screen goes black and the computer restarts. No BSOD, no information.

I've recently replaced my SSD and I've reinstalled Windows and I'm starting from scratch. Now when I try to run the tests to estimate the Windows Experience Index I do get a BSOD. Currently I'm interacting remotely and can't actually see the BSOD. Instead, when it boots back up I see the "Windows recovered from a crash" dialog with sparse info about the failure. The dialog says this:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   116
  BCP1: FFFFFA80196CB010
  BCP2: FFFFF8800F4525C8
  BCP3: FFFFFFFFC00000B5
  BCP4: 000000000000000A
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\092514-51261-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Corey\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-52385-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

A little googling shows that [the BCCode of 116 is a VIDEO_TDR_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557263(v=vs.85).aspx). Eventually I'll replace both cards, they've both mined the same number of hours, but in the mean time I only want to replace the card that is primarily causing this error.

Can I determine through logs or software which card is at fault for this? I know I can try removing one card and seeing if it still crashes, but I'm hoping to find a way to do this without the potential of inducing another failure. I believe the repeated crashes is what broke my old SSD (that coupled with old age, the tower is about 4 years old).

GeForce Experience claims that the 344.11 drivers are the latest non-beta drivers for the cards and they're successfully installed.

The dump file (at C:\Windows\Minidump\092514-51261-01.dmp) is filled with hex data that doesn't seem too helpful and is too big for pastebin. The xml cannot be found at the indicated location.

Comment: You have no supplied enough information to help you.  There is a .dmp file but you don't indicate which drivers were loaded.  You don't indicate what version of those drivers are loaded.  Without this information we can't help you.  Cards are designed to be used, its very unlikely, you shortened their lifespan.

Comment: Have you done any basic physical checks? Fans running? Heat-sinks clogged? IME, just pull one card at a time, it's the easiest method; especially since you already reinstalled Windows.

Comment: Fans seem to be running fine and everything is well dusted and cleaned out. I'll be updating with dump data and driver versions here shortly.

Comment: we can't debug this type of crash with the debug data that Microsoft gives us. You must remove one card and look if you stll get issues with the other one

Comment: There are programs like BlueScreenViewer that can help understand a dmp file

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you'll be able to accurately determine which card is at fault without removing one card at a time and testing the system. This is not only the simplest and most reliable method at your disposal, but to your advantage, you now have the ability to reproduce they problem on-demand, making the task of figuring out which card is to blame even easier.

You'll truly save yourself a lot of hassle by employing the good 'ol swap-n-test method.

Comment: This is eventually what I had to do. With a little educated guessing, I determined the card in the first slot was most likely the issue.  After removing it and moving the other card up, I played games for hours.